# Manual disk partitions - moving to Kubuntu from Fedora

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, kubuntu, encryption, fedora

Currently running Fedora 26 KDE Spin. And want to shift to Kubuntu 17.04.

My current disk partitions are (output of lsblk):

```
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   200M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                                          8:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot
├─sda3                                          8:3    0   3.5G  0 part  
│ └─luks-ea1b71f7-6d0b-4073-bdaa-6d5382cee00c 253:1    0   3.5G  0 crypt [SWAP]
├─sda4                                          8:4    0  49.4G  0 part  
│ └─luks-42eeceb3-d4ba-4f21-9fac-0e546edba366 253:0    0  49.4G  0 crypt /
└─sda5                                          8:5    0 411.7G  0 part  
  └─luks-3e9b5ec1-10f9-4a5b-a986-6e9c61cb7f5a 253:2    0 411.7G  0 crypt /home
sr0                                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

My /home is on a separate encrypted partition. I want to retain and use it as it is. Everything else can go.

In Kubuntu 17.04 installation, I chose 'manual partitioning' option and tried marking sda5 to be used as /home without formatting and chose Ext4 as a filesystem type. But it always forces formatting.

What am I doing wrong and how do I install Kubuntu without losing my data?

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the filesystem forces formatting. Don't select a filesystem.

Comment: But I want to use that (sda5) as my home partition. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Hmm. I think it's because the partition is encrypted - it doesn't recognise an ext4 filesystem and wants to format it. In that case, install without setting a `/home`, and the modify `fstab`, etc. to mount it after installation.

Comment: You mean to say that I delete or format other partitions, leave sda5 untouched during installation and install without specifying a home partition. Correct? Also, any ideas about edits needed for fstab later?

Comment: Yes, that's about it.

Comment: @deshmukh  Check Kubuntu's current fstab (and crypttab, IIRC) to see how it's mounted now.

Comment: is it possible to install without a /home? Do I set up the user (same as it was in Fedora). Sorry, I'm asking too many questions. But you can imagine worries of a newbie :)

Comment: If you install without a `/home` partition, you'll find `/home` in your root partition, and the user setup during installation (it will ask for username, pass, etc.) will have its home directory there. You can later mount over that home directory.